# Pre-execute external javascript for every page in firefox

Tags: javascript, preload

Is there any method that I can pre-execute some javascripts for every page in firefox?
I have tried the greasemonkey extension, but the script is executed after page loaded.
I would like the "pre-executed" solutions.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem do you try to solve?

Comment: i think if you put the javascript in the head it will execute the script before the page is completely loaded

Comment: A video object is called in every html page. However, the video object is undefined. I have implemented the video object by javascript (video.js) and I have to modify every page to include the "video.js". The modification is difficult cause that there are too many html pages.

Answer (score 0):

that is an old post but I think you should consider using **'on load'** body property.
If you call your **video object** on load, the page would have been completely load and ready to execute your object that have been loaded before.

Already solve that kind of **synchronization Pb** before with this little option.